# Compare std::function created with std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

Here is a toy example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Obj
{
  int x;

  int foo()
  {
    return 42;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Obj a, b;
  std::function<int()> f1 = std::bind(&Obj::foo, &a);
  std::function<int()> f2 = std::bind(&Obj::foo, &b);
  std::function<int()> f3 = std::bind(&Obj::foo, &a);
  std::function<int()> f4 = std::bind(&Obj::foo, &b);
}
```

How can I verify that `f1 == f3` and `f2 == f4`, where the `==` comparator, here, means that both `std::function` objects correspond to the same method of the same object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

If you want `==` you'll have to write your own type erasing wrapper, possibly using `std::function` to store state.

As `std::bind` does not support `==` and neither does lamba, you'll have to inject a custom function object that *does* support `==` to be type erased.

None of these are easy.  Alternative solutions, like registering binds with names, will be more practical.